# Connect Ubuntu 14 server to the Internet

Tags: server, vmware, dhcp

I just installed Ubuntu 14 server in my [VMware](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VMware) workstation 11. What should I do to get an Internet connection?

Because I need to install the package `isc-dhcp-server`.

Answer (score 0):

I did a little bit of research, and I found this resource [here](http://wiki.opencog.org/w/Setting_up_Ubuntu_in_VMWare_for_Noobs). If this resource does not help you, then you can try [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads).

Comment: I bridge the network already for my ubuntu server but still i can ping to any website. Because i need to use this command line "sudo apt-get update".

Comment: So then what is your question?

Comment: Ubuntu 14 server have an internet connection in vmware.

Comment: Sorry for the first comment have typo error still i can't* ping to any website.

Comment: have you by chance tried to use virtualbox yet? It should just work right out of the box.